# Drag a uiview along a line path

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my app i have an `UIview` which consists of multiple `uiview` as subviews. i want to drag an single UIView in a **straight line** horizontally, i used `SetCenter` property but it's not working. 
my code:

```
   CGPoint translatedPoint = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[myview superview]];

    if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        _firstX = [myview center].x;
        _firstY = [myview center].y;
    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(_firstX+translatedPoint.x, _firstY+translatedPoint.y); 

    [myview setCenter:translatedPoint];
```

Here when i start dragging the `myview` it moves along with my mouse pointer position. But i want to drag only in a HORIZONTAL path(i.e, Straight Line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGPoint translatedPoint = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[myview superview]];

    if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        _firstX = [myview center].x;
    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(_firstX+translatedPoint.x, _firstY); 

    [myview setCenter:translatedPoint];
```

Comment: what will be the value of _firstY?

Comment: haven't you already assigned a value to the variable _firstY when you defined it?

Answer (score 3):

So just update the x coordinate and not the y.